# Hindi characters in url parameter in java

Tags: java

I am working on language identifier where i need to pass the text to server and identify the language where I'm trying to pass the Hindi characters through **URL** to server.How can i pass the Hindi characters as URL parameter in java.please somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your URL using [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). Just use URLEncoder.encode method, something like this:

```
String yourEncodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(yourURLWithHindiCharacters, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: If the receiving service happens to be a Java servlet / JSP (and the charset encoding is not explicitly defined in the request), the encoding should be `"ISO-8859-1"`, which is the default expected per the Servlet specification.